# Error al emplear la función JSON.parse() de javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, postgresql

A partir de un query, donde hago uso de la función de postgres `jsonb_agg()` obtengo la estructura de un arrego de objetos en forma de un string, uso una propiedad computada para disponer de su valor en forma de arreglo de objeto, dada las [recomendaciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) de MDN no deseo usar `eval()`  pero `JSON.parce` me genera el error: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data".

La forma como empleo ambas funciones las detallo a continuación:

```
computed: {
    areas: function(){
        return JSON.parse(this.propertyInfo.func_appraisal_areas_json)
    }
},
```

Usando `JSON.parse()` obtengo el siguiente error:

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

```
computed: {
    areas: function(){
        return eval(this.propertyInfo.func_appraisal_areas_json)
    }
},
```

Usando `eval()` si obtengo la estructura del arreglo de objetos correctamente, pero la idea de emplear una función que recomiendan no usar, a pesar de que funciona, no resulta de mi agrado.

He intentado también usar `JSON.stringify()` para asegurar que el string disponga de la estructura correcta, pero el error obtenido es el mismo.

```
computed: {
    areas: function(){
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.propertyInfo.func_appraisal_areas_json))
    }
},
```

A modo de ejemplo, cuando por la consola de javascript reproduzco el contenido de `this.propertyInfo.func_appraisal_areas_json` la forma del string es:

```
    console.log(this.propertyInfo.func_appraisal_areas_json)
```

[{"name": "Parqueos", "area_id": 1, "dimension": 35}, {"name": "Sala de Juegos", "area_id": 5, "dimension": 50}]

```
    console.log(typeof(this.propertyInfo.func_appraisal_areas_json))
```

string

Comment: `jsonb_agg` devuelve un valorJSON binario, ese es el problema que veo yo. Intenta usar `json_agg` que si devuelve una cadena JSON

Comment: asegurate utilizar parse cuando obtengas el resultado

if(this.propertyInfo && this.propertyInfo.func_appraisal_areas_json){
   // do any stuff
}

Comment: La cadena debe tener algo más... prueba esto: `let tx = '[{"name": "Parqueos", "area_id": 1, "dimension": 35}, {"name": "Sala de Juegos", "area_id": 5, "dimension": 50}]'; let ob = JSON.parse(tx); console.log(ob);`, que funciona sin inconvenientes.

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente el problema era que en la instancia o momento en que se evaluaba la función el valor de this.propertyInfo.func_appraisal_areas_json no se había obtenido aún.  Al probar por la consola del navegador "JSON.parse()", sin pasar ningún string obtengo el mismo error.

Hice estos ajustes a mi función computada y el problema se solucionó "return (this.propertyInfo.func_appraisal_areas_json) ? JSON.parse(this.propertyInfo.func_appraisal_areas_json) : null"